# Correct useage of Application.GetContentStream while debugging and click once publishing

Tags: xml, wpf, clickonce

As per my previous question, [publishing a content file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37401826/correctly-using-and-publishing-a-content-file-in-visual-studio-2015), I have this setup:

- A "content" file of PrinterMap.xml with:

  - *Build Action*: **Content**
  - *Copy to Output Directory*: **Copy Always**
- Physical location of this file during development at: `C:\Nova6\PrintingAndReports\Settings\PrinterMap.xml`

Assuming I have the correct Uri for the PrinterMap.xml, does `Application.GetContentStream(Uri)` allow for both debugging where the build process places the *PrinterMap.xml* in the `C:\Nova6\Nursing_Desk\bin\Debug\Settings` directory and for the click once published directory of `C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\3RPPH36W.WAY\MN0L8QBO.1R4\nurs..tion_f6d771115904d935_0001.0000_f6a09aea8a2c02e5\Settings\ReportMap.xml`?

That is, can I use `Application.GetContentStream(Uri)` while debugging this app or is there a better way or preferred program design?
Is there a best practice here? (And what is the correct Uri to do this?)

Thanks for any guidance with this.

Comment: Did you try `Application.GetContentStream(new Uri("/Settings/ReportMap.xml", UriKind.Relative));`?

Comment: @sthotakura  Thanks for your reply. That string works when stepping through the debugger, but failed when running the published exe. My application crashed. Additional information: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Alan Wayne\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\3RPPH36W.WAY\MN0L8QBO.1R4\nurs..tion_f6d771115904d935_0001.0000_f6a09aeb8aab12a5\Settings\ReportMap.xml'.        :(

Comment: Did you check if the file exists in that location (C:\Users\Alan Wayne\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\3RPPH36W.WAY\MN0L8QBO.1R4\nurs..tion_f6d771115904d9‌​35_0001.0000_f6a09aeb8aab12a5\Settings)?

Comment: @sthotakura  Yes. It does.

Comment: Please refer to the last answer in this [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-us/81fe0552-540c-4d7b-b732-6904b5f2120d/application-content?forum=wpf). It says something clickonce and xml files being treated differently by clickonce applications.

Comment: @sthotakura I was wrong.Searching the folders shows that the ReportMap.xml is NOT in the ...e5\Settings directory, but rather it is in ..e2\settings and  ..e3\settings directories---but not ..e5. So why is Application.GetContentStream() getting the wrong directory which clickonce is clearly creating?

Comment: @sthotakura.  Hmm...When I completely uninstalled the previous application, then reinstalled it...It does seem now to run (without crashing).  I guess by simply installing the new published app, the previous ReportMap.xml file was not getting rewritten???  It seems to work without crashing now.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `GetContentStream` specifying only the file name, so the directory will be automatically set to the execution assembly location (i.e. current folder).

Alternatively, if you do not want to expose the file to the file system and embed it in your assembly (usually it would be better if your assembly does not depend on external files), use [`Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream) instead, for example:

```
using var stream =
  Assembly
    .GetExecutingAssembly()
    .GetManifestResourceStream("Resources.PrinterMap.xml");
```

You can also add the resources using the project properties.
Right-click current project and go to properties, then navigate to the *Resources* tab, Click the arrow next to *Add Resource* and select *Add Existing File...*:

[image]

Which in case you can access the file directly as such:

```
byte[] myXmlFile = MyProject.Properties.Resources.PrinterMap;
```

You can also add the XML data as a string and parse the XML directly.